# How can I stop my arraylist being put multiple times into my shared preferences file?

Tags: java, android, gson, android-sharedpreferences

The arraylist should be of the form, `[{"12345"}, {"67890"}, etc...]`

But when I close my app - I mean press the back button the amount of times it takes to get back to the Android home screen - and then restart it, I see `MatchingContactsAsArrayList`is`[{"12345"}, {"67890"}, etc...,{"12345"}, {"67890"}, etc...]`

If I close it twice, the `arraylist` comes up 3 times and so on, it keeps getting longer. It should just display each value once.

I thought                             `editorMatchingContactsAsArrayList.remove(jsonMatchingContactsAsArrayList).commit();`
would take care of this.

Here's my code:

```
        @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                //convert the JSONArray, the response, to a string
                String MatchingContactsAsString = response.toString();

                //make an arraylist which will hold the phone_number part of the MatchingContacts string
                MatchingContactsAsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

                try {
                    JSONArray Object = new JSONArray(MatchingContactsAsString);
                    for (int x = 0; x < Object.length(); x++) {
                        final JSONObject obj = Object.getJSONObject(x);
                        MatchingContactsAsArrayList.add(obj.getString("phone_number"));

                    }

                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesMatchingContactsAsArrayList = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editorMatchingContactsAsArrayList = sharedPreferencesMatchingContactsAsArrayList.edit();
                    Gson gsonMatchingContactsAsArrayList = new Gson();
                    String jsonMatchingContactsAsArrayList = gsonMatchingContactsAsArrayList.toJson(MatchingContactsAsArrayList);
                    editorMatchingContactsAsArrayList.putString("MatchingContactsAsArrayList", jsonMatchingContactsAsArrayList);
                    editorMatchingContactsAsArrayList.remove(jsonMatchingContactsAsArrayList).commit();
                    editorMatchingContactsAsArrayList.commit();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
```

Comment: Check if the key exists before you add to it

Answer (score 1):

`SharedPreferences.remove()` method takes in the `key` that you used to save.

Which in this case is "MatchingContactsAsArrayList".

And actually, you don't need to use `remove()`, because `putString()` with an existing `key`, will override that value. Please make sure that the data from response is correct.

Comment: I tried all these things - clear(), remove(), nothin was working.

But you are right - my response was not correct. For the arraylist on which my response was based I put arraylist.clear() and now it is working correctly.